# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency'

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, exception, uiviewcontroller

Originally wrote my code in a previous iOS and just upgraded to iOS 6.1 only to receive the following error. I'm a novice so forgive me if this is a basic question but i haven't figured out how to fix this. Tell me what code to include if this doesn't give enough of a picture and I'd be glad to post it. Full Error:

---

`2013-06-28 17:44:06.007 DrinkMixer[5747:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <UITableView: 0x81f0a00; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x723bac0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x723b480>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> is associated with <UIViewController: 0x723cb00>. Clear this association before associating this view with <MasterViewController: 0x7141860>.`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have multiple UIView's on the root of your viewController. Add the other views as subviews of the main view and the error will go away.